# Leaving undergraduate schools attended off grad applications

Tags: graduate-admissions

Grad applications usually list all undergraduate coursework. Is it necessary to list all schools attended, even ones I did not graduate from?

Answer (score 4):

Do the application instructions say to list (and/or supply transcripts from) all of the institutions you have attended previously? If they ask for *all* of it, that's what you have to give them.